# Get Bootstrap table into JSON using Angular

Tags: angular, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I got this Bootstrap table :

```
  <table class="table table-striped" id="mainTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Dossier n°</th>
          <th scope="col">Nom du dossier</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let dossier of dossiers">
          <td>{{dossier.id}}</td>               
          <td>{{dossier.student.major}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and I would like to download everything in the table as JSON (to get it in CSV after). Do you know anything that could help me ? Thanks you

Comment: Since the data is in the `dossiers` property, you can do `JSON.stringify(this.dossiers)`.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan, I didn't think about it, even if it was obvius...

Comment: You are welcome. :-)